# Delete parts of a matrix that satisfy a condition in R

Tags: r

I would like to delete rows from a large matrix using the following criteria:

Any row that contains 100 in its second column should be removed.

How can this be done? I know how to select those rows but I'm not sure how to remove them using a rule.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
R > mat = matrix(c(1,2,3,100,200,300), 3,2)
R > mat
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1  100
[2,]    2  200
[3,]    3  300
R > (index = mat[,2] == 100)
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
R > mat[index, ]
[1]   1 100
R > mat[!index, ]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2  200
[2,]    3  300
```

Previously I was confused by the index with another method `which`, here is the solution by `which`:

```
R > (index2 = which(mat[,2] == 100))
[1] 1
R > mat[-index2, ]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2  200
[2,]    3  300
```

Watch out the different use for those index (`!` and `-`).

Comment: this is strange it works with your example but not with my dataset. any ideas why?

Comment: And I guess you first column might be the row number.

Comment: No you have to delete the first column, that's just a result of read.csv in the original file there's no first column. a=a[,-1] and then try your code. it still won't work

Comment: @user1723765 The first column is a result a `write.csv`, you can set `row.names = FALSE` when you export.

Comment: Yep. I guess when you `write.csv` , you can change the option `row.names` to `FALSE`.

Comment: as Arun said, in your 3-column data, there is no 100 in your 2nd column.

Comment: okay then remove the first column which will make it a 2column data and try the code. it still doesn't work

Comment: I am so sorry. There is a typo in my previous answer. Please replace `-index` by `!index` in the last statement. Then the result would be the new data without 100 in 2nd column

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it in Matlab with a matrix `A`.

**Option 1**

```
for (i=size(A,1):-1:0)
    if (A(i,2)==100)
        A(i,:)=[];
    end
end
```

This loops over rows (starting at the bottom), and sets any row with 100 in the 2nd element to an empty set, which effectively deletes it.

Maybe you can convert this to r, or maybe it will help somebody else who is having this problem.

**Option 2**

```
logicalIndex=(A(:,2)==100);
A(logicalIndex,:)=[];
```

This first finds rows with 100 in the 2nd column, then deletes them all.